# gdb disassemble: show function offsets in base 16

Tags: gdb, linux-kernel, backtracking

When disassembling functions, *gdb* will  display memory addresses in base 16, but offsets in base 10.

Example:

```
(gdb) disassemble unregister_sysctl_table
Dump of assembler code for function unregister_sysctl_table:
   0x00037080 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x00037081 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00037083 <+3>: sub    $0x14,%esp
   0x00037086 <+6>: mov    %ebx,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x00037089 <+9>: mov    %esi,-0x8(%ebp)
   0x0003708c <+12>:mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x0003708e <+14>:mov    %edi,-0x4(%ebp)
```

The function offsets are the `<+N>` next to the address, and as you can see they are in base 10.

When the Linux kernel crashes, it displays a backtrace using base 16:

```
 [    0.524380]  [<c10381d5>] unregister_sysctl_table+0x65/0x70
```

It's very annoying to have to convert backtrace addresses from base 16 to base 10 to be able to find the desired instruction.

Can *gdb* be told to display disassembly output with base 16 offsets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GDB currently uses hard-coded '%d' for the offset.

> It's very annoying to have to convert backtrace addresses ... to be able to find the desired instruction

You do realize that you can simply do

```
x/i 0xc10381d5       # the crashing instruction (if looking at the inner frame)
x/i 0xc10381d5-5     # the call (if looking at caller frame)
x/10i 0xc10381d5-20  # context around the desired location
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to patch gdb to show offset in hex.

for example, in gdb 6.8,

change *_field_int in cli-out.c, mi/mi-out.c, tui/tui-out.c

```
void
cli_field_int (struct ui_out *uiout, int fldno, int width,
enum ui_align alignment,
const char *fldname, int value)
{
char buffer[40]; /* FIXME: how many chars long a %d can become? */


cli_out_data *data = ui_out_data (uiout);
if (data->suppress_output)
    return;
sprintf (buffer, "%d:%X", value, value);
cli_field_string (uiout, fldno, width, alignment, fldname, buffer);
```